# Clarification regarding [vr] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

With the increasing proliferation of virtual reality systems in recent years, I have noticed many more questions with this tag.

Usually it accompanies a more specific tag which describes the system, like google-vr or gear-vr. Although, I'm sure that this is not always the case.

Is this tag too broad to stand on its own? In my mind this is a tag that should only be used when the question is about vr, but sufficiently cross device/platform. If the question is about a specific platform, it should just have the platform tag, right?

At the very least, its wiki should be updated to advise when to and not to use the tag. I wanted to see whether I was thinking about this correctly, hence meta question.