# Synonym request for [augmented-reality] and [ar]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I've just found two tags that mean the same: [augmented-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) and [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar).

[augmented-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) got 1,554 questions and [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar) got 218 questions. I prefer to keep the [augmented-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) because it's much clearer to me.

Could anyone make a synonym?

**P.S.:** I've also found this tags: [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality) and [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr). More information on this question: [Synonym: [virtual-reality]/[vr]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343910/synonym-virtual-reality-vr).

Comment: `ar` appears to be a bit of a mess at the moment - its tag wiki states: *the Unix archiver utility, used primarily for maintaining static libraries. For questions about augmented reality, use "augmented-reality", not this tag* - since people aren't following that advice it's being used for both.  A straight-forward synonym wouldn't be appropriate here. Looks like it could do with someone proposing a plan on how to tidy it up.

Comment: @JonClements I would vote for `[ar]` to be renamed and subsequently blacklisted to avoid the `[bootstrap]` havoc... only I have no idea what else to call the `ar` utility. :/

Comment: @Siguza ar-fileformat? ar-archive-format?

Comment: More bikeshedding: ar-static-library, ar-linking, ar-binutils, ar-unix.

Comment: I'd suggest `[gnu-binutils-ar]` or `[binutils-ar]` (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/binutils/ar-cmdline.html + https://www.lifewire.com/ar-linux-command-4093866 "ar is considered a binary utility because archives of this sort are most often used aslibraries holding commonly needed subroutines")

Comment: In my opinion, variants on the GNU binutils ar naming is not appropriate for the `ar` tag because there are certainly multiple implementations of `ar` that are not from GNU.  In my view, the `ar` tag is correct and any `augmented-reality` questions with the `ar` tag simply need to be retagged to `augmented-reality`.

Comment: Not very related, but I have [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343907/clarification-regarding-vr-tag) same question regarding the `augmented-reality` tag.

Comment: ar is one of the oldest C build tools out there, with dozens of variations.  It deserves its own tag, and there is no other reasonable synonym for it-  I would never search for anything other than ar to find questions on it.  Clean up the tag if needed, but it should not be synonymed for augmented-reality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update 2021-02-11

Despite this request being marked status-declined, the original `ar` tag has been renamed to `unix-ar` and plain `ar` is now a synonym for `augmented-reality`.  I'm not clear where this was discussed.  The change occurred earlier this week (I got an `ar` email on the 9th; I got `augmented-reality` emails from the 10th).  I was subscribed to get emails about the `ar` tag and suddenly they all contained the tag `augmented-reality` instead of `ar`.

---

#### Answer 2017-05-08

[Jon Clements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) points out in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348843/synonym-request-for-augmented-reality-and-ar#comment471197_348843) that [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar) has a wiki description:

> The Unix archiver utility, used primarily for maintaining static libraries. For questions about augmented reality, use "augmented-reality", not this tag.

It is simply not appropriate to retarget the [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar) tag when it has a long history of being used correctly for the Unix archiver.  I note that the `ar` tag was in use for the `ar` command for years before people tried to augment it to mean [augmented-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality).

---

AFAICT, after some tag changes and other editing (81 revised questions, if I counted correctly), all the 131 questions still tagged [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar) are now related to the Unix `ar` command and not to augmented reality. It's possible I missed a few, but there shouldn't be many interlopers.

There were a number of questions tagged [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) with [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar); in the statistical world, it appears that AR is used as an abbreviation of auto-regression or thereabouts.

The [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar) tag does not need modifying, IMO.  It already points people to use the [augmented-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) for augmented reality.

For the few questions that I came across with both [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) and [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar), the [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) is now [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality).  I didn't go on a campaign to change other [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) questions.

Comment: I somehow missed this meta. I can revert this if need be. I thought the rename would keep subscriptions as they were and I guess that's not actually the case.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about the change. I would have continued to advocate against it, but now that it is fait accompli I think it can stay.  I don't know how many times I retagged questions.  It averaged a couple a day, I think; certainly multiple times a week.  It will save me that effort.  I don't recall what alternative names were suggested before for the old ar tag, but the new name is about as good as it gets.